# Using enumeration to represent error messages legibily - is it good practice?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, enums

I'd like to consolidate my error messages and stuff into one file, and make my code more readable if possible.

Here's an example of what I have in my enum file:

```
public enum ZipErrorType {

// START: define exception messages (alphabetical order)
EMPTY_FILE_NAME_IN_LIST {
    public String toString() {
        return "One or more null/empty filename(s) found";
    }
},

FILE_DOESNT_EXIST {
    public String who(String sThisFile) {
        return "[" + sThisFile + "] does not exist";
    }
},

FILE_LIST_IS_NULL {
    public String toString() {
        return "File list is null/empty";
    }
},

FILENAME_NOT_ABSOLUTE {
    public String who(String sThisFile) {
        return "[" + sThisFile + "] is not absolute";
    }
},

MUST_BE_DIR {
    public String who(String sThisFile) {
        return "[" + sThisFile + "] must be a directory";
    }
},

MUST_BE_FILE {
    public String who(String sThisFile) {
        return "[" + sThisFile + "] must be a file";
    }
},

NULL_OR_EMPTY {
    public String who(String sThisFile) {
        return "[" + sThisFile + "] is null/empty";
    }
},

OUTPUT_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS {
    public String who(String sThisFile) {
        return "[" + sThisFile + "] already exists";
    }
},

OUTPUT_FILENAME_EMPTY {
    public String toString() {
        return "Output filename is null/empty";
    }
},

OUTPUT_PATH_EMPTY {
    public String toString() {
        return "Output path is null/empty";
    }
},
// END: define exception messages

NONE {};

public String who(String sThisFile) { return ""; }
}
```

Then in my program I have code like:

```
private static ZipErrorType getFileErrorsIfAny(String sFilename, boolean shouldBeFile) {

    // check if given filename is absolute
    File file = new File(sFilename);
    if (!file.isAbsolute()) {
        return ZipErrorType.FILENAME_NOT_ABSOLUTE;
    }

    // check if file exists
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return ZipErrorType.FILE_DOESNT_EXIST;
    }

    // check if corresponding file is a file when it shouldn't be...
    if (file.isFile() && !shouldBeFile) {
        return ZipErrorType.MUST_BE_DIR;
    }
    // ...or a directory when it should be a file
    else if (file.isDirectory() && shouldBeFile) {
        return ZipErrorType.MUST_BE_FILE;
    }

    return ZipErrorType.NONE;
}
```

...and an example of how I make use of my enum:

```
    // check input files
    for (String sFile : files) {
        if (sFile == null || sFile.trim().length() == 0) {
            throw new NullPointerException("One or more filename is null/empty");
        }

        errorIfAny = getFileErrorsIfAny(sFile.trim(), true); 
        if (!errorIfAny.equals(ZipErrorType.NONE)) {
            throw new ZipInputException(errorIfAny.who(sFile.trim()));
        }
    }
```

Now I know it's hard to judge just by these code snippets alone, but is this alright, from a general perspective? Is what I'm doing not worth the trouble, and is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Consider posting this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. It seems you do not have any problems or question, but just need peer review.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's better or not, but in my current project we are using enums in the same way... but the String returned by each one is just an identifier used for i18n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using simple string templates instead of enums for building error messages.
Something like this:

```
String EMPTY_FILE_NAME_IN_LIST_TEMPLATE = "One or more null/empty filename(s) found";
String FILE_DOESNT_EXIST_TEMPLATE = "[ %s ] does not exist";
String FILE_LIST_IS_NULL_TEMPLATE = "File list is null/empty";
String FILENAME_NOT_ABSOLUTE_TEMPLATE = "[ %s ] is not absolute";
String MUST_BE_DIR_TEMPLATE = "[ %s ] must be a directory";
String MUST_BE_FILE_TEMPLATE = "[ %s ] must be a file";
String NULL_OR_EMPTY_TEMPLATE = "[ %s ] is null/empty";
String OUTPUT_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS_TEMPLATE = "[ %s ] already exists";
String OUTPUT_FILENAME_EMPTY_TEMPLATE = "Output filename is null/empty";
String OUTPUT_PATH_EMPTY_TEMPLATE = "Output path is null/empty";
```

And then, use `String.format(template, sFilename)` for building actual message.

You may also consider throwing an exception right out of `getFileErrorsIfAny()` method:

```
File file = new File(sFilename);
if (!file.isAbsolute()) {
    throw new ZipInputException(String.format(FILENAME_NOT_ABSOLUTE_TEMPLATE, sFilename));
}
```

Looks cleaner and more compact to me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have the potential to result in many many massive `enum`s dotted around the code.

This isn't the first time someone has wanted to separate of the log message from the log statement.

In fact [`java.util.logging`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) already has a [framework for this](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/logging_localized_message) that is designed for localisation.

It uses a `.properties` file which contains the messages.
You get the logger with the path to the file in the classpath : -

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.example", "path/to/messages.properties");
```

Logging statements are then done using the property keys

```
logger.log(level, "messageKey");
```

And you can parameterise the logging because it uses [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) syntax

```
zip.fileDoesNotExist={0} does not exist

logger.log(level, "zip.fileDoesNotExist", file);
```

These parameters are extremely flexible as you can specify formatting information in them and even use [`ChoiceFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) if needed.

The main advantage of all this is that your messages are in a separate file, rather than a `class`. **And** you can turn logging on and off at will with the `logging.properties` file. You can even turn logging on and off for single classes. **And** you can log to multiple files, to the console, you can send emails on errors etc etc

**So, in conclusion. Use an existing logging framework. Don't roll your own.**

*Disclaimer: I only talk about JUL because then is built into Java - you don't need any 3rd party libs, there are many, many other frameworks out there.*